# Dual boot Ubuntu(studio) and windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

My Windows 10 was working normally, I've space and decided install Ubuntu. Proceeded as all the tutorials, but now I've Ubuntu working and no dual boot at all -> Directly Ubuntu, no questions. The windows files are there,on disk, but grub cannot find the windows boot.

Comment: try repairing your boot manger using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows is installed in? If not, boot installer USB in same mode as Windows and reinstall Ubuntu using `Something else`.